# Multiple socket streams in PHP

Tags: php, sockets

In PHP, my script is **only trying to test if a server is online** - nothing more. How would I go about creating multiple socket streams that all run at the same time? Doing it one-after-another would take forever if you're testing a bunch of servers.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would start a pool of [threads](http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php) and the threads would read all the sites that need to be tested from a queue.  This would allow each thread to open a connection to a site (supporting concurrency)

or maybe [`pthreads`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php)? I dunno, i've never written threaded code in php

Comment: no, don't use threads.   Threads are a horrible way of handling IO for an arbitrary number of connections (at least 1:1 -- N:M is very good, but is much more difficult)  See my answer for a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Use [select](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php).  This takes a list of which sockets you want to read or write to and then tells you when they are ready.  When you read/write to these, you know you'll be able to get/send some data.  You then process what you need to do on those sockets, and go back and select again waiting for more data.

If you need to do other things as well, set the timeout on select and it will return in that amount of time, even if nothing is ready on any sockets.

edit: also, once you figure out how to use select (not that hard), it's a TON simpler to debug and deal with than dealing with synchronization between threads.

Comment: stop the fear mongering ... select() is the best suited for the task at hand, but don't go throwing around sweeping statements about something that, it doesn't appear at least, you tried ...

Comment: @JoeWatkins fear mongering seems a bit harsh.   When you're dealing with complex systems, avoiding threads does everyone involved a huge favor.  And you'd never find a port scanner implemented with threads.

Comment: as a matter of unarguable fact, the _most_ complex systems we all use (that's operating systems, which extends to the internet at large) would not work anywhere near as well as they do if it weren't for concurrent computation ... additionally, a port scanner is not anything like a complex system, I already said select() is best for the task at hand ...

Comment: @JoeWatkins I didn't say it was impossible or never the correct solution.  I also didn't say that port scanners were complicated -- I said you'd never find one using threads.  Separately in complicated systems threading becomes difficult and if you're asking this question on SO, you're probably not a experienced kernel developer.

Comment: You made a stupid statement, with no basis in reality: "When you're dealing with complex systems, avoiding threads does everyone involved a huge favor." This is what I was responding too ...

Comment: @JoeWatkins and I'll stick to that -- as a general rule for most developers.